# Cannot delete entity

Tags: 8, entities

I'm unable to delete a custom entity. I'm getting the following error

```
$storage_handler = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage("notification_storage");
$notification_entities = $storage_handler->loadMultiple($notifications['notification']);
$storage_handler->delete($notification_entities);
```

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException : Route "entity.notification_storage.canonical" does not exist. dans Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (ligne 202 de /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

```
/**
 * Define NotificationStorage entity.
 *
 * @package Drupal\notification\Entity
 *
 * @ContentEntityType(
 *   id = "notification_storage",
 *   label = @Translation("Notification Storage"),
 *   handlers = {
 *     "view_builder" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder",
 *     "list_builder" = "Drupal\notification\Controller\NotificationStorageListBuilder",
 *     "views_data" = "Drupal\notification\NotificationViewsData"
 *   },
 *   base_table = "notification_storage",
 *   entity_keys = {
 *    "id" = "id",
 *    "uuid" = "uuid",
 *    "langcode" = "langcode"
 *   },
 *   fieldable = TRUE,
 *   links = {
 *     "canonical" = "/admin/notification_storage/list"
 *   },
 *   field_ui_base_route = "notification_storage.settings"
 * )
 */
```

Comment: is the value of `$notifications['notification']` an array of ID's ?

Comment: Well, the obvious error would be `entity.notification_storage.canonical` not being defined. Whats that come from? Was that module disabled?

Comment: @Kevin you define the entity canonical in the entity type annotation itself, thats probably where it’s missing from. I’d wager it’s a form state redirect trying to forward to the canonical but not being able to find the route

Comment: @clive I've updated the code with the annotation

Comment: @Kevin I've updated the code with the annotation

Answer (score 1):

You've defined a canonical link in the entity annotations, but this doesn't build a route automatically. If you don't want to do specify the route in a yaml file you need a route provider:

```
 *   handlers = {
 *     "route_provider" = {
 *       "html" = "Drupal\Core\Entity\Routing\DefaultHtmlRouteProvider",
```

If the custom entity should be part of the admin interface use [AdminHtmlRouteProvider](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Routing%21AdminHtmlRouteProvider.php/class/AdminHtmlRouteProvider/8.5.x).